# How to forward page from react js frontend to node js backend using proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I created a simple react app that has two pages ("/", "/show-stocks") using Routes to switch between the two. I created a node/express js backend that has an end point called "/show-stocks/btc", I setted the proxy in the `package.json` to `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000/"`, Now I want to be able to forward to the backend the page "/show-stocks/btc" (the preset end point).

I tried this solution but it didn't worked. It does take the user to /show-stocks/btc but in the localhost:3000 and sends an error that says that this path does not exsist.
I saw on the internet that if the page does not exists its automatically checks if the proxy has it.

> **(React listening on port 3000, Node listening on port 4000)**

###### Does someone know how can I implement this?

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ShowStocks from "./components/pages/ShowStocks";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/show-stocks" element={<ShowStocks />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ShowStocks.js**:

> (incase user goes to "localhost:3000/show-stocks")

```
import React from "react";
import "../../App.css";

import GetStocks from "../../GetStocks";

export default function ShowStocks() {
  return (
    <>
      <GetStocks />
    </>
  );
}
```

**GetStocks:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "react-axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class GetStocks extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      BTCprice: "Noy Yet Gotten",
    };
  }

  getBTC = () => {
    // here I am trying to get response from the proxy /show-stocks/btc end point.
    axios.get("/btc").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.price);
      this.setState({
        BTCprice: response.data.price,
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>BTC price: {this.state.BTCprice}</h1>
        <Link to="/show-stocks/btc" className="btn-mobile">
          <button className={`btn--test`} onClick={this.getBTC}>
            Get price
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

the problem where at GetStocks.js

this is the new code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class GetStocks extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      BTCprice: "Noy Yet Gotten",
    };
  }

  getBTC = () => {
    console.log("jey");
    axios.get("/show-stocks/btc").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.price);
      this.setState({
        BTCprice: response.data.price,
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>BTC price: {this.state.BTCprice}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.getBTC}>Get price</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```